# How to encode List when deploying a smart contract through mxpy?

Tags: smartcontracts, multiversx, erdpy

When using the MultiversX SDK, I can pass a list of typed values as a single Input argument to a smart contract deploy, with the method `List.fromItems(arrayTypedValue)`.

How can I encode the same `List` input when deploying through the `mxpy` CLI?
Something like `mxpy contract deploy ... --arguments <List>`.
How do I encode the `<List>` here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize each variable in the array (according to [this documentation](https://docs.multiversx.com/developers/data/serialization-overview/#arrays-and-tuples)) and then send them as a continuous string preceded by `0x` which should mark it as an encoded string. For example, the array `[1, 1]` becomes `0x0000000100000001` which has 3 parts:

- `0x`
- `00000001`
- `00000001`